# Update an XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

PHP is not my world so, I need some help to update a xml file.
It's my first time with DOM  and seems to not replace the element.

**Here's my XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feedback>
  <feed id="0">
    <title>some title</title>
    <desc><![CDATA[some text]]></desc>
  </feed>
  <feed id="1">
    <title>some title</title>
    <desc><![CDATA[some text]]></desc>
  </feed>
  <feed id="2">
    <title>some title</title>
    <desc><![CDATA[some text]]></desc>
  </feed>
</feedback>
```

**And PHP code:**

```
<?php

    if ($_POST['agg']) {

        $selid = $_POST['selectedfeed'];
        $newtitolo = $_POST['title'];
        $newdesc = nl2br($_POST['feed']);

        $file = "feedback.xml";
        $fp = fopen($file, "rb") or die("cannot open file");
        $str = fread($fp, filesize($file));

    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xml->loadXML($str) or die("Error");    

    $root = $xml->documentElement;

    $oldfeed = $root->getElementsByTagName("feed")->item($selid);

    $title = $xml->createElement("title");
    $titleText = $xml->createTextNode($newtitle);
    $title->appendChild($titleText);

    $desc = $xml->createElement("desc");
    $descText = $xml->createCDATAsection($newdesc);
    $desc->appendChild($descText);

    $feed = $xml->createElement("feed");
    $feed->appendChild($title);
    $feed->appendChild($desc);

    $root->replaceChild($feed,$oldfeed);

    $xml->saveXML("feedback.xml");
    }
?>
```

For the code above, I need to get a "feed" node with a specific ID and replace the feed's content with the new created elements "title" and "desc" (cdata).

How can I do this?

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: it don't update anything... :(

Comment: What I meant was that you are sharing your code but not telling us what the problem is. You are not showing us the error you get. You are not asking a specific question. You are not presenting a current behaviour versus an expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost every thing in your code is Ok.
Just change:

```
 $xml->saveXML("feedback.xml");
```

to

```
 $xml->save("feedback.xml");
```

Comment: This part is incorrect `$oldfeed = $root->getElementsByTagName("feed")->item($selid);`

Answer (score 0):

Use DOMDocument::getElementById()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) to find the feed you need.

```
$oldfeed = $xml->getElementById($selid);
```

---

Then use [DOMDocument::save()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) to save the XML to file.

```
$xml->save('feedback.xml');
```

---

The DOMDocument::save() takes a filename as the first parameter. DOMDocument::saveXML() takes a DOMNode as the first argument and echoes the content (it does not save it).

Comment: i got this error:Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::getElementById()

Comment: My bad, i looked at your code and confused $root for $xml. the `getElementById()` method is defined for the `DOMDocument` class.